# How to hide the "Data Dictionary" from the Alfresco Repository?

Tags: repository, hide, admin, alfresco, data-dictionary

I am new to alfresco. I am integrating Alfresco with the web application as an library for my application. I am logging to alfresco as a admin and I can see the Data Dictionary in my repository. I want to hide it. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? Is it enough to stop the Data Dictionary from being displayed, or do you really have to prohibit access for some reason ?

Comment: Hi  Andreas Steffan.Because in my web application, I am providing a link to library.i.e when i click on that link, it will take me to alfresco dashboard(i have hard coded the username and password as admin). I have hidden the login page of alfresco, instead I am passing the username and password to the javascript, where it submit the login form. I want to hide dictionary because all the users who clicks on the library link of my application, will login as admin(because i have hard coded the username & password as admin). so once the my app user logs in, Data-Dictionary  will be visible to him.

Comment: I aslo tried to create a alfresco user. But when i tried, it displayed the following  error "Failed to create the user: 05190030 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 05192817 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/person/people.post.json.js': Non-unique path: found : /app:company_home/app:user_homes 0."

Answer (score 3):

In order to hide the Data Dictionary folder for normal users you have to properly configure permissions. By default, all folders in Alfresco use the default ACL, which makes everyone Consumer (i.e. read only). This is what makes them visible to every user.

Try one the following:

[From Alfresco Explorer]

- log in as admin
- go to Data Dictionary
- click on More Actions -> Manage space users
- remove the only one entry you have there

[From Alfresco Share]

- log in as admin
- go to Repository
- if needed, click on "Show folders"
- hover on Data Dictionary
- click on More -> Manage Permissions
- hover on the Actions column, click Delete

This way you hide the Data Dictionary folder to normal users. Admin users always get access to everything. With similar procedures you can configure more fine grained access levels on folders, e.g. to enable some users to access them.

Comment: Are you sure this works without severely degrading repo functionality for users ? I think there is various general functionality which requires read permissions. Templates are an example I am thinking of.

Comment: Are you talking Space templates or Presentation templates? The former don't need to reside in Data Dictionary, and the latter.. well, it's just sadist to let your users be on Explorer nowadays. I'm pretty sure if the OP wants to hide Data Dictionary, his users don't need access to it anyway.

Comment: Well in fact, I was thinking about the email templates in particular. Of course you are always free to move stuff around, change the system accordingly and then prohibit access to the DD. At the end of the day, I wonder whether doing so actually solves the problem at hand.

Comment: Thank you  skuro for the reply. I have set the permission. But I am not able to create the user. I got the following error "Failed to create the user: 05190030 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 05192817 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/person/people.post.json.js': Non-unique path: found : /app:company_home/app:user_homes 0."

Comment: If I can create the user for alfresco then it would help me.

Comment: @than1234 that's a [known issue](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-670) if you renamed or moved the `User Homes` folder.

Comment: @skuro thank you for the reply. I had deleted User Homes. now i re-installed alfresco.I was able to create user and hide Data-Dictionary. Thank you bro. Have a nice day.