# How to create a User in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, createuser

I tried creating a user. But when I tried, it displayed the following error:

> Failed to create the user: 05190030 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 05192817 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/person/people.‌​post.json.js': Non-unique path:found : /app:company_home/app:user_homes 0." I am new to Alfresco. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That path looks very strange. Can you provide the JSON you are posting?

Answer (score 1):

This pretty much sounds like you try to create a user which already exists (username property is unique).

Comment: thank you bro for your reply. I reinstalled alfresco, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082534/how-to-hide-the-data-dictionary-from-the-alfresco-repository/11083115#comment14534408_11083115) to your other question, it's a [known issue](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-670) when you move, delete or rename `User Homes`.

Comment: Yes u had mentioned. One more help bro. In the repository there will different document lists.i.e there will Data dictionary, user homes etc. when i change the view to "detailed view", it displays Favorite, like, comments links. where will i have to modify if I dont want to show them. Can you tell in which file i have to comment the code for not displaying those links. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: It's best if you create another question, as it's completely unrelated to this one. It would make it impossible for other people with the same issue to find the proper answer here.